# Mojave 10.14.3 required for app submission

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store-connect, macos-high-sierra

I have a Mac Pro 2010 with the 2.4 GHz Q. Core Xeon E5620 and i am now unable to submit any applications to the app store. I must have at least Xcode 11 to submit an app [as per this link](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/). Xcode 11 requires Mojave 10.14.3+ but the machine i have says i cant update the OS to Mojave.

Is there anything i can do at all, other than purchasing another system? Or have Apple screwed me over?

Anyone else managed to get around this issue without having to buy a new machine?

Comment: This may help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327375/can-a-flashed-mac-pro-2009-5-1-support-macos-mojave

Comment: Yes i saw a few links referring to the dosdude patch, but i was hoping to avoid flashing the machine, as it will be very expensive if it goes wrong.

Comment: not the best solution i suppose but would virtualisation work? running a virtual machine with mojave?

Comment: Tried that previously, which is why i purchased the machine. Somehow Apple know that i'm not using Apple branded hardward when attempting to deploy to store connect when running in VM